# Jenkins Pipeline Docker -- Container is Not Running

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have Jenkins running on an EC2 Instance.  I have the EC2 Plugin Configured in a Peered VPC, and when a job is tagged 'support_ubuntu_docker' it will spin up an Jenkins Slave, with Docker pre-installed.

I am able to follow the examples, and get my job to connect to the local docker running on the Slave, and run commands inside the container.

Working: https://pastebin.com/UANvjhnA

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { 
            image 'node:7-alpine' 
            label 'support_ubuntu_docker'
             }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not Working https://pastebin.com/MsSZaPha

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { 
            image 'hashicorp/terraform:light' 
            label 'support_ubuntu_docker'
             }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'terraform --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried with the ansible/ansible:default image, as well as a image I created myself.

```
FROM alpine:3.7
RUN apk add --no-cache terraform
RUN apk add --no-cache ansible
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/ash"]
```

This image behaves locally.

```
[jenkins_test] docker exec -it 3843653932c8 ash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   10:56:42  ☁  master ☂ ⚡ ✭
/ # terraform --version
Terraform v0.11.0

/ # ansible --version
ansible 2.4.6.0
  config file = None
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.15 (default, Aug 22 2018, 13:24:18) [GCC 6.4.0]
/ #
```

I really just want to be able to clone my terraform git repo, and use the terraform in the container to run my init/plan/applies.

The error im getting for all of these is.

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to run top 'c9dfeda21b718b9df1035500adf2ef80c5c3807cf63e724317d620d4bcaa14b3'. Error: Error response from daemon: Container c9dfeda21b718b9df1035500adf2ef80c5c3807cf63e724317d620d4bcaa14b3 is not running
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question really should have been a Docker question; what's the difference between `node:7-alpine` and `hashicorp/terraform:light`?

`hashicorp/terraform:light` has an `ENTRYPOINT` entry, pointing to `/bin/terraform`.
Basically that means you run it this way:
`docker run hashicorp/terraform:light --version`
And it will exit right away, i.e., it's not interactive.
So if you want an interactive shell within that Docker container, you'll have to override the `ENTRYPOINT` to point at a shell, say, `/bin/bash` and also tell Docker to run interactively:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { 
            image 'hashicorp/terraform:light' 
            args '-it --entrypoint=/bin/bash'
            label 'support_ubuntu_docker'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'terraform --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've upvoted this because it addresses the root of the problem but this doesn't work for me while the answer by S.Spiker works.

Answer (score 8):

I had to change the entrypoint to empty to get it working with the following script it worked like a charm:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
        image 'hashicorp/terraform:light'
        args '-i --entrypoint='
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            sh 'terraform --version'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In a scripted pipeline you can do this:

```
docker.image(dockerImage).inside("--entrypoint=''") {
    // code to run on container
}
```

If you are creating the image to use in Jenkins from a base image that already has an ENTRYPOINT instruction, you can override it by adding this line to the end of your own Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT []
```

Then the whole --entrypoint is no longer needed.

Comment: I know. It doesn't answer the question but it does add useful information for people who aren't using declarative pipelines.

Comment: how do we pss credentials to access this image?